# What's the meaning of "Acme developers for IPhone"?

Tags: meaning

I have recently heard the term "Acme developer of IPhone." I was just wondering what it stands for?

I think I know the meaning: Is it when a developer goes to a client and presents his/her ideas for the app?

Comment: Please post where you saw this - we need context

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Acme* is a sort of tongue-in-cheek reference to any company or person that develops over the top answers to simple problems. The Wile E. Coyote cartoons Robusto mentions have pushed the pop culture meaning into something that is considered bombastic or extravagant. The devices and plans that were used on the show were often punny or taking advantage of cartoon tropes for a cheap laugh. As such, they were never *serious* solutions for catching the Road Runner.

An Acme iPhone Developer would be an iPhone Developer who develops oddball or crazy apps that seek solely to entertain. *Or* they would be a developer who considers themselves much, much better than they really are — they think they are a big player when they only push out meaningless applications. The exact meaning would need a little more context.

Comment: Interesting new use, we used to use it for exactly the opposite - as a synonym for common-or-garden. The ACME solution was the generic one from some unknown company bolted together from VB and access.

Comment: @mgb: Interesting. I can see how that would work and will file it away for future reference. :) Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any citation for this being how people use the word?  I've always seen Acme used as a generic---an Acme iPhone developer would be one of a million fly-by-night companies churning out generic apps.

Comment: @Henry: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acme_Corporation) talks about the influence of the show. The word itself means _peak_ or _best_. The idea of an Acme developer churning out generic crap matches my intention with this sentence: "they think they are a big player when they only push out meaningless applications." Essentially, if the developer is calling itself Acme, it is a joke. If other people are calling the developer Acme, they make crap.

Answer (score 1):

*Acme* is a word meaning "highest point"; it is also the company that makes the equipment that this guy:

[image: Wile E. Coyote]

(Wile E. Coyote) used for (unsuccessfully) hunting this guy:

[image: Road Runner]

(Road Runner) in Looney Tunes cartoons.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wile_E._Coyote_and_Road_Runner

Comment: what, no latin names?

Answer (score 0):

Programmers have something called a ["metasyntactic variable"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metasyntactic_variable). Acme is the logical extension, a metasyntactic company. See also [Acme::Metasyntactic](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/4302285/dir//com/perl-Acme-MetaSyntactic-0.13-1mdk.noarch.rpm.html)

Comment: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=558220